# Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to int

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass data to a datatable in laravel 5 but have the following error

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to int

the error line is one which corresponds to where I am selecting desired information from my model `

```
$query= ChangedProperties::select('changed_property','change_type','previous_value','updated_value')->get();`
```

any ideas ?

Comment: you are sending a object type data to insert into a integer type column in database. you said you are passing data to database but the gave code of reading data from database. please give proper code so we can understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above returns collection object,

```
$query= ChangedProperties::select('changed_property','change_type','previous_value','updated_value')->get();
$value1 =  $query->changed_property;
$value2 =  $query->change_type;
...
```

insert those variables to each of the required fields that match datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `contains()` method that is available to you.